# Merge incoming array document to existing document with elasticseach script in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, array-merge

I want to merge new document to existing document. My existing document is like that:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "recall": [
            { 
                "title": "xxx-a",
                "date": "2020-12-10"
                "otherB": "abc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the new inserted document is like that:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "recall": [
            { 
                "title": "xxx-b",
                "date": "2021-12-10"
                "otherB": "abcd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want the output as:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "recall": [
            { 
                "title": "xxx-a",
                "date": "2020-12-10"
                "otherB": "abc"
            },
            { 
                "title": "xxx-b",
                "date": "2021-12-10"
                "otherB": "abcd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using logstash to load data to ES. My current script is this:

```
script_lang => "painless"
script =>"if (ctx._source.containsKey('recall'))ctx._source.recall.addAll(params.event.recall);}"
```

But it gives me this output which is append the inserted doc to existing not merge:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "recall": [
            { 
                "title": "xxx-a",
                "date": "2020-12-10"
                "otherB": "abc"
            },
          [
            { 
                "title": "xxx-b",
                "date": "2021-12-10"
                "otherB": "abcd"
            }
          ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your script to this:

```
script =>"if (ctx._source.containsKey('recall'))ctx._source.recall.addAll(Arrays.asList(params.event.recall));}"
```

Comment: ...[0] will only take the first element not the full array

Comment: That's what your example shows